# Encountering an Anaconda Error When Opening

Tags: python, anaconda

I have used Python via Anaconda successfully since initially installing it years ago. However, when attempting the open Anaconda this morning after restarting my computer, I encountered the following error, which I believe has something to do with my IT department. Seeing I have trust issues with my department, I wanted to reach out here to see if this is something that looks familiar/or if anyone knows of a solution.

```
Dell Intel(R) Core (TM) -i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60 GHz
Installed RAM 16.0 GB
System type 64-bit OS, x64 -based processor
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version: 1803
OS build: 17134.2208
```

[image]

```
Navigator Error
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

Report
Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker

Main Error
[WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\conda-meta'
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 151, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash, tab_project=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 372, in __init__
    self.tab_learning = CommunityTab(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\tabs\community.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.list = ListWidgetContent()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\lists\content.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.tracker = GATracker()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 295, in GATracker
    GA_TRACKER = _GATracker()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 134, in setup
    pkg_version(pkg='pyqt5', name='root')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 1460, in package_version
    for package in self.linked(prefix):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 678, in linked
    fname for fname in os.listdir(meta_dir)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\conda-meta'
```

Comment: Please add the error as text, not an image to your question.

Comment: Does `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\conda-meta` exist and you have permission to access that folder? What is it that you suspect your IT department did on your computer?

Comment: I do have access to that pathway when I search for it in my files - just heard back from IT, they suspect the following: "Lead suspect for the culprit is now MS Edge based on timing of updating Edge recently"